# MCAR : Probability that data is missing

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, python

I have a project that I am working on and would like a pointer to help me move forward in the correct direction.  I have a very large dataset, about 5 million lines, and I performing missing data analysis on a few of the columns.  For example, I am trying to see if a pair of variables, **region number** and **company code**, affects the missing data in another column like **revenue**.

I am only interested in seeing how these two variables (region and code) could predict whether data is missing or not in other columns.  So I'm asking, what's the probability that revenue is missing given a certain combination of region and code?

At the start, this looks like a logistical regression problem, where I remap the **revenue** column to 1 or 0 (present/missing) and model the other variables of interest.  However, I believe the data is probably over-fitting because I am getting 0% error.  Am I approaching this problem entirely wrong?
  Is there anything else I should worry about?  Both region number, which ranges from 1 - 10 and company code (0 - 9999) are probably both categorical variables, but I haven't tried any types of encoding yet.  Here's a snippet of code :

```
data = df[['code','region','revenue']]

data['revenue'] = data['revenue'].replace(0, np.nan) # Fill zeroes with NaN
data['revenue'] = ~data['revenue'].isnull()*1 # Convert to binary TRUE/FALSE

y_data = data['revenue']
classifier = linear_model.LogisticRegression(n_jobs = -1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, y_data, test_size = 0.5)
columns = X_train.columns.tolist()
classifier.fit(X_train[columns], y_train)
pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Ultimately I am trying to prove that revenue is MCAR.